# How do I replace a token with the result of `pwd` in sed?

Tags: unix, sed

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
sed 's/#REPLACE-WITH-PATH/'`pwd`'/'
```

Unfortunately, I that errors out:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unknown option to `s'
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to use a different character instead of `/`, eg.:

```
sed 's?#REPLACE-WITH-PATH?'`pwd`'?'
```

because `/` appears in the `pwd` output.

Comment: very interesting, I was wondering what the error meant. great job

Answer (score 3):

in sed, you can't use / directly, you must use '/'.

```
  #!/bin/bash
  dir=$`pwd`/
  ls -1 | sed  "s/^/${dir//\//\\/}/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's:#REPLACE-WITH-PATH:'`pwd`':' config.ini
```

The problem is one of escaping the output of `pwd` correctly. Fortunately, as in vim, sed supports using a different delimiter character. In this case, using the colon instead of slash as a delimiter avoids the escaping problem.

Answer (score 1):

instead of fumbling around with quotes like that, you can do it like this

```
#!/bin/bash
p=`pwd`
# pass the variable p to awk
awk -v p="$p" '$0~p{ gsub("REPLACE-WITH-PATH",p) }1' file >temp
mv temp file
```

or just bash

```
p=`pwd`
while read line
do
    line=${line/REPLACE-WITH-PATH/$p}
    echo $line    
done < file > temp
mv temp file
```

Comment: I was trying to do somewhat similar, this helped me...   
I used it like this : `project_dir=${current_dir/\/f1\/f2//}`   
I wanted the path to 2 folders up.