# Getting bad flag in substitute command '/' for sed replacement

Tags: bash, sed

I am facing one issue while using replace in my sed command. I've a file named `a.txt`, I want to replace a single line with some other line but I am getting above mentioned error.

**Code I want to replace:**

```
DOMAIN_LOCAL = "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
```

I want it to replace with any other ip lets say something like below:-

```
DOMAIN_LOCAL = "http://127.1.1.2:3000";
```

What I've tried:-

```
ip=http://127.1.1.2:3000
sed "s/DOMAIN_LOCAL = .*$/DOMAIN_LOCAL = "$ip";/g" a.txt
```

But it is giving me following error. Can somebody help here.

```
sed: 1: "s/DOMAIN_LOCAL = .*$/DO ...": bad flag in substitute command: '/'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will need to use another delimiter. And escape the `$` or use single quotes:

```
% ip="http://127.1.1.2:3000"
% sed 's~DOMAIN_LOCAL = .*$~DOMAIN_LOCAL = "'"$ip"'";~' a.txt
DOMAIN_LOCAL = http://127.1.1.2:3000;
```

When you use `/` as a delimiter in the `s`ubstitute command it will be terminated at the first slash in `http://`:

```
sed 's/DOMAIN_LOCAL = .*$/DOMAIN_LOCAL = http://127.1.1.2:3000;/'
#                                             ^ here
```

Breakdown:

```
sed 's~DOMAIN_LOCAL = .*$~DOMAIN_LOCAL = "'"$ip"'";~' a.txt
#   │                                    ││└ Use double quotes to avoid word splitting and
#   │                                    ││  globbing on $ip
#   │                                    │└ Exit single quotes
#   │                                    └ Literal double quotes
#   └ Using single quotes to avoid having to escape special characters
```

Comment: I want it with double quotes something like `DOMAIN_LOCAL = "http://127.1.1.2:3000";`

Comment: Basically what is happening is whenever I am using `'/'` as a delimiter it will stop the replacement as soon as it finds the forward slash. Is it correct?

Comment: @DisplayName Yes, one thing to note is that the variable `$ip` is expanded before the sed command is invoked. So sed doesn't know that the slashes in `http://` is literal slashes and *not* a delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

You may need another delimiter instead of `"/"`, for example `"%"`.It worked for me.

Comment: this answer could be improved with an example; I found this example useful... all "/" must be replaced ... with in the link example was "?" http://stackoverflow.com/a/1186199/5283424

Answer (score 2):

use # replace / to avoid this issue
`$ sed 's#find#replace#' file`